# Dhtmlx scheduler- connect to database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am using a plugin called DhtmlxScheduler:http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxScheduler/index.shtml
 the way it is structured is kinda confusing for me .How am I supposed to conntect it to mysql database using php, so the events will save to my database. Usually I would make a form with an action attribut that processes the data and saves it to mysql.

Answer (score 0):

As you probably know, dhtmlxScheduler is a client-side plugin consisting of HTML/JS/CSS. You will need to integrate the scheduler with server-side scripting. Typically, you would fire requests based on events that occur within the calendar. Think of the dhtmlxScheduler as providing the forms that you typically wrote, and the actions are going to happen only when some event is triggered in the scheduler.

For more information, you should take a look at the documentation found here: http://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/server_integration.html

Here's a list of events you can play off of:
[http://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/api_*refs*_scheduler.html#events](http://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/api__refs__scheduler.html#events)

That should at least get you pointed in the right direction.